# Node.js ffmpeg creating a mp4 video from 2 or more jpg images

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, mp4

I am making a video animator that first generates `.jpg` images from an html `canvas` tag and then use the images as frames for the video. I am using `ffmpeg` to do the video generating.

**It works when only using 1 image**

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath("C://Program Files/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe");

var command = ffmpeg();

command
    .input("./test.jpg")
    .save("./test.mp4")
    .outputFPS(1)
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log("done");
    });
```

I got it to make a mp4 video that is 1 second long with this code, but this is only with one image/frame.

**What I'm trying to do (2+ images)**

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath("C://Program Files/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe");

var command = ffmpeg();

command
    .input("./test.jpg")
    .input("./another.jpg")
    .save("./test.mp4")
    .outputFPS(1)
    .frames(2)
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log("done");
    });
```

This doesn't work as it generates the same video as the first example. Instead of showing one image for the first second and another image for the second second, it generates a one second long video that only has the first image.

Can someone please show how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. After looking in documentation it seems that the only way to add two images as inputs is to use a image file pattern.

I just had to name the images in a pattern like

```
image0.jpg
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
```

Or with additional preceeding 0s if I want 10+ or 100+ images.

Now I can just do `command.input("./image%1d.jpg")`.
Hope this helps people in the future who had the same problem as me.

Comment: Hey could you please share a working snippet? I'm trying to make a video from 75 jpgs @1fps and all I get is a 5 seconds vid

Comment: I can't make a snippet because ffmpeg is in Node.js. How many images do you have?

Comment: I know fluent-ffmpeg is in node, you could just paste the lines where you use it. Anyway I figured out how to use it by myself